# How to use ACF image field in css with media queries using Timber template engine?

Tags: twig, wordpress-theming, advanced-custom-fields, custom-wordpress-pages, timber

I'm writing wordpress theme using Tiber and have really interesting case regarding different images on mobile and desktop.

Case:
I would like to upload 2 images (mobile and desktop version) using Advanced Custom Field PRO in Wordpress and use them in custom Timber template engine theme.

Code:

.twig

```
 <div class="application--main-image"></div>
```

.scss

```
.application-main-image {
  background-position: center bottom;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url('../img/mobile.png');
  @media (min-width: 600px) {
    background-image: url('../img/desktop.png');
  }
}
```

I found that I should use inline-style to put `{{ post.image }}` inside `background-image` but what about media queries?

Should I make some `custom attributes` or style inside `.twig` file with `<style></style>` but I want to use scss so it's not the case.

How would you solve that problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is certainly a unique use case, here are my thoughts on how I would approach this:

```
<style>
  .application--main-image {
    background: url('https://source.unsplash.com/500x500/?ocean');
    /* The actual URL would be replaced by your ACF Filed {{ post.mobile_image }} */
  }

  @media (min-width: 600px) {
    .application--main-image {
      background: url('https://source.unsplash.com/500x500/?mountain');
      /* The actual URL would be replaced by your ACF Filed {{ post.desktop_image }} */
    }
  }

</style>

<div class="application--main-image"></div>
```

I think you are correct in that you will need to add the  tags and the css necessary to your .twig template. I know you want to use .scss, however you only really need to change the background image property. I have create a JS fiddle to show you what I mean.

https://jsfiddle.net/robertguss/2kacx91k/7/

I hope that helps. If you have already come up with a solution that is different than mine, please share it here so not only I can learn but others in the future as well.

Cheers.